# Need to Trigger Change Detection in Angular App

Tags: angular, accordion, angular-changedetection

I'm creating an accordion element, and in this accordion element, I can add new lists which are also accordion elements. Once this new list is created, I need the newly created list to expand. I'm running into a change detection issue and I'm new to Angular, so forgive me if this is obvious. Right now, if I create a new list, let's call it "List 1," it does not expand. But if I then create "List 2", "List 1" will expand. I'm trying to call detectChanges with the ChangeDetectorRef, with no success. I've also tried markForCheck() with no luck. I have confirmed that the newly created list is bound, and coming back as anticipated; it just isn't expanding when I want it to. Any guidance?

```
openAddChecklist() {
    let config = new MatDialogConfig<CardVM>();
    config.data = this.card;
    config.width = '800px';
    config.height = '350px';


    config.viewContainerRef = this.viewContainerRef;

    let dialogRef = this.matDialog.open(CreatechecklistComponent, config);
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((d: TaskListVM) => {
      this.openChecklist =  this._verifyType(d);
      this.findPanel('Checklists')
      this.expanded(this.openChecklist);
      // this.cdr.detectChanges(); <-- I tried calling it here as well with no success
    })
    this.cdr.detectChanges();

  }

  expanded(checklist: TaskListVM) {
    checklist.isExpanded = true;
    this.checklistService.manageExpanded(checklist, true);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

In most cases detecting changes is implemented inside ngOnChanges(). That is part of lifecycle hook. More about it here: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

In your case try to implement that interface and try to detect changes inside it, like this. Keep in my mind that it will reflect in given component (in case below change detector will detect changes within MyComponent):

```
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  constructor(private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
      this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
    // use console.log(changes) to see if changes are detected
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually make any sense. ngOnChanges is an interface method on Angular components that fires *in response to detected changes* and provides you a list of *what those changes were*.

Triggering change detection *inside of ngOnChanges* is redundant, and will (or should, if you're not writing really weird code), effectively be a no-op.